# DirectShow filter DebugAssert info level

Tags: filter, directshow

I am currently developing DirectShow renderer (audio visualizer), but I am getting ASSERT error when I quit app, telling

szInfo  0x000000e313f8e530 L"Executable: WinDMC.exe  Pid 1fe0  Tid 4768. Module AudioVisualizer.dll, 5 objects left active! \nAt line 350 of C:\Users\Hiroyuki\source\repos\App\baseclasses\dllentry.cpp\nContinue? (Cancel to debug)"

Can anyone tell me how to know the names that are active, not only the number of objects?
MessageBoxOtherThread() doesn't show up to UI(don't know why), so I capture the string to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

DirectShow BaseClasses don't track leaked instances, it's just a global counter. You need to guess, or you can edit [baseclasses\dllentry.cpp](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow/baseclasses/dllentry.cpp#L348) file and add more diagnostic code to identify/log pointers that remain active.